# How to update NPM 6.13.4 to 7.16.0 on Mac?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm studying Laravel, and after I run the command **npm run dev**, I saw these messages:

**New major version of npm available! 6.13.4 → 7.16.0**

**Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.16.0**

**Run npm install -g npm to update!**

But when I run the command: **npm install -g npm** on terminal, I get a lot of messages about permissions:
[image: NPM errors]

The command **sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/myfolder/.npm"** doesn't change anything. I tried to clear the cache with:

**npm cache clean --force**

Still nothing.

I don't know much about npm and I have this problem on my mac for a long time, since I can't find a way to solve this. I don't even know how to completely remove npm/node. So, I'm pretty stuck.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Install latest version

Permission problem solve

```
sudo chown -R user:group folder
sudo chmod -R 755 folder
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: Hi, still the same. Same errors appearing.